# Create a plot for each unique ID

Tags: python, matplotlib

Given the dataframe df, I could use some help to create two different scatter plots one for the x,y cordinates, the c value is used for the color map with the id "aa" and one with the x,y cordinates, the c value is used for the color map  with the id "bb".  With the actual data there are over 1000 unique id's.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pyodbc
import pandas as pd


#need to add the 
data = {'x':[2,4,6, 8,10, 12], 'y':[2,4,6, 8,10, 12], 'c': [.2,.5,.5,.7,.8,.9], 'id':['aa','aa','aa','bb','bb','bb']}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

print (df)

for d in df.groupby(df['id']):

    plt.scatter(d[1][['x']],d[1][['y']], c=d[1][['c']], s=10, alpha=0.3, cmap='viridis')
    clb = plt.colorbar();
    plt.show()
```

Returns this error: ValueError: RGBA values should be within 0-1 range

Comment: It'd be easier to help you if you post what code you've tried so far and where you ran into issues, but in case you're not sure where to begin, I'd suggest [pandas.groupby](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/groupby.html).

Comment: Thank for the recommendation, I have updated the original post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

for d in df.groupby(df['id']):
    plt.plot(d[1][['x','y']])
    plt.show()
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked but I realized I needed to specify a Scatter Plot.  I also added a value to dataframe that is to be used in a color map.   I tried to adapt the solution you recommended by I am getting an error.

Comment: Sorry I cannot reporduce your error, `plt.scatter(d[1][['x']],d[1][['y']], c=d[1][['c']], s=10, alpha=0.3, cmap='viridis')` works for me. I suppose your color column, which is `'c'`, has been modified accidentally.

Comment: Thank you, my issue is with the values for 'c'.